# I deleted and reinstalled Tomcat8, now it won't start ... says "tomcat not installed" ... how do I determine what's wrong?

Tags: 18.04, apt, init.d, tomcat

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

I "apt installed" tomcat8 and it was working fine ... until I messed up the configuration.  So I "apt removed" it and manually deleted folders `/usr/share/tomcat8` and `/var/lib/tomcat7`.

Then I reinstalled it with ...

```
sudo apt install tomcat8-admin
sudo apt install tomcat8
```

But when I do this to start it ...

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat8 start
```

I get ...

```
[....] Starting tomcat8 (via systemctl): tomcat8.serviceJob for tomcat8.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tomcat8.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

When I do ...

```
sudo journalctl -xe
```

... it says ... "tomcat8 is not installed" and "tomcat8.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'" and "Unit tomcat8.service has failed"

How do I re-install tomcat8 and/or figure out why it won't start?

Full output of `sudo journalctl -xe` follows:

```
-- Unit tomcat8.service has begun starting up.
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 tomcat8[20746]:  * tomcat8 is not installed
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspe
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
-- Subject: Unit tomcat8.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit tomcat8.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspe
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspe
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspe
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspe
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspe
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspe
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspe
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspe
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspe
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 rsyslogd[20535]: action 'action 8' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), next retry is Thu Sep 17 17:05:23 2020, retry nbr 0. There should be messages
Sep 17 17:04:53 ip-172-31-27-106 sudo[20734]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 17 17:08:06 ip-172-31-27-106 sshd[20780]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 45.227.255.204 port 51400 [preauth]
Sep 17 17:08:34 ip-172-31-27-106 sudo[20783]:   ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log/tomcat8 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Sep 17 17:08:34 ip-172-31-27-106 sudo[20783]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
tail -f /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out
```

As you restart tomcat.  For me I found,

```
root@stage-damageid4:~# tail -f /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2110586880 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid2714.log
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=2096m; support was removed in 8.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000742330000, 2110586880, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

Which means I was specifying too much memory for the JVM.